# Can we close file descriptors 3 and 4? I'm having trouble with it

Tags: c, pipe, valgrind, file-descriptor

I am facing challenges with managing file descriptors in my C program, specifically in the context of my Pipex project. Upon program exit, Valgrind reports that 5 file descriptors are open, with 3 being standard descriptors. In particular, file descriptor 5 was opened with the pipe function in the pipe.c file at line 29, called from the here_doc function at address 0x109622 in my program.

I have included a snippet from the Valgrind report below for reference:
[valgrind 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yzNw.png)
[valgrind 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIlQY.png)

code :
pipex.c

```
#include "../inc/pipex.h"

char    *find_path(char *cmd, char **ev)
{
    char    **allpaths;
    char    *exe;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    while (ev[i])
    {
        if (ft_strnstr(ev[i], "PATH=", 5) != NULL)
            break ;
        i++;
    }
    allpaths = ft_split((ev[i] + 5), ':');
    i = 0;
    while (allpaths[i])
    {
        exe = build_executable_path(cmd, allpaths[i]);
        if (exe != NULL)
        {
            ft_clear_tab(allpaths);
            return (exe);
        }
        i++;
    }
    ft_clear_tab(allpaths);
    return (NULL);
}

void    exe(char **ev, char *av)
{
    char    **cmd;
    char    *cmd_exe;

    cmd = ft_split(av, ' ');
    cmd_exe = find_path(cmd[0], ev);
    if (cmd_exe == NULL)
    {
        perror("pipex: command not found");
        ft_putendl_fd(cmd[0], 2);
        ft_clear_tab(cmd);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (execve(cmd_exe, cmd, ev) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipex: execution error");
        ft_putendl_fd(cmd[0], 2);
        ft_clear_tab(cmd);
        free(cmd_exe);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void    do_pipe(char **av, char **ev)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     fd[2];

    if (pipe(fd) == -1)
        error_arg();
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        exe(ev, av[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }
}

void here_doc(char *limiter, int ac)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char *line;

    if (ac < 6)
        error_arg();

    if (pipe(fd) == -1 || (pid = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("Pipe or Fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);

        while (gnl(&line) > 0)
        {
            if (ft_strncmp(line, limiter, ft_strlen(limiter)) == 0 || line[0] == '\0')
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
            write(fd[1], line, ft_strlen(line));
        }
        free(line);
        close(fd[1]);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
int main(int ac, char **av, char **ev) 
{
    int in;
    int out;
    int i;

    if (ac < 5)
        error_arg();
    if (ft_strncmp(av[1], "here_doc", 8) == 0) 
    {
        i = 3;
        out = open(av[ac - 1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
        if (out == -1)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        here_doc(av[2], ac);
    } 
    else
    {
        i = 2;
        out = open(av[ac - 1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0777);
        in = open(av[1], O_RDONLY, 0777);
        if (out == -1 || in == -1)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        dup2(in, 0);
    }
    while (i < ac - 2)
        do_pipe(av + i++, ev);
    dup2(out, 1);
    exe(ev, av[ac - 2]);
    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;
}
```

utils.c

```
#include "../inc/pipex.h"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100000

void    error_arg(void)
{
    write(2, "\033[1;31m!! we need more than 5 arguments :c !!\n\033[0m\n", 49);
    write(2, "\033[1;32mExample: ./Here_doc cmd1 cmd2 outfile\033[0m\n", 50);
    write(2,
        "\033[1;32mExample 2: ./pipex infile cmd1 cmd2 cmd3 ... outfile\033[0m\n",
        65);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gnl(char **line)
{
    char *buffer;
    int i = 0;
    int r;
    char c;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(10000);
    if (!buffer)
        return (-1);
    while ((r = read(0, &c, 1)) > 0 && c != '\n' && c != '\0')
        buffer[i++] = c;

    buffer[i] = '\0'; 

    *line = buffer;

    if (r > 0 || i > 0)
        return (1); 
    else
        return (r);
}

void    ft_clear_tab(char **tab)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    while (tab[i])
    {
        free(tab[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(tab);
}

char    *build_executable_path(char *cmd, char *path)
{
    char    *part_path;
    char    *exe;

    part_path = ft_strjoin(path, "/");
    exe = ft_strjoin(part_path, cmd);
    free(part_path);
    if (access(exe, F_OK | X_OK) == 0)
        return (exe);
    free(exe);
    return (NULL);
}
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Can't you close before leaving do_pipe?

Comment: I would like to close all my file descriptors at the end of my program. I'm not referring to the default file descriptors, but the ones created for the pipe (specifically, file descriptors 3 and 4)

Comment: When a process exits, all its fd's are closed automatically.

Comment: Even for file descriptors other than stdin, stdout, stderr because in this case, it's not those. I added new a screenshot of my Valgrind ?

Comment: Please post the valgrind output as text, not a screenshot.

Comment: What is `in` for? You open it in the `else` block, but never use it. And if you don't go into the `else` block, you'll try to `close(in)` even though it's uninitialized.

Comment: Why have you used the magic number `1` instead of `STDOUT_FILENO` when calling `dup2()` in `main()`? You clearly know better in `do_pipe()`.

Comment: Yes, *all* of a process's open file descriptors are closed automatically when the process terminates.  Valgrind is reporting that some of your FD fall through to that automatic closure, not that they are never closed at all.  This can be a sign of trouble if you thought you did explicitly close all your FDs, but it has no effect on the system that lasts past the process's termination.

Comment: 1 = stdin that's why I did that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you dup one of the pipe FDs to stdin or stdout, you no longer need the original pipe FD to be open. So the code that redirects should look like:

```
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        exe(ev, av[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }
```

In `main()`, you need to `close(out)` after you dup it. You're doing that after you call `exe()`. But `exe()` never returns, because it calls `execve()`. So move that call before the call to `exe()`.

```
    dup2(out, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(in);
    exe(ev, av[ac - 2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reminder; it was an oversight on my part, but it still doesn't resolve the issue of my file descriptors not being closed.

Comment: Found the problem - you're not closing `out`.

Comment: he errors on Valgrind have reduced significantly, there is only one remaining. Thank you

Comment: There's no formatting in comments, so that's unreadable.

Comment: That's `in`. You're not closing that before calling `exe()`.

Comment: yet so I have indeed included the configuration file with the executable."

Comment: If you have `dup2(in, STDIN_FILENO);` somewhere, you need to put `close(in);` after that, not after `exe()`.